# PHP: Could not make sqlite3 database

Tags: php, sqlite

I wanna create a sqlite3 database in PHP but I get an error from PHP

**Error**

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: Unable to open database: unable to open database file
```

**Codes**

```
$database = new SQLite3('myDatabase.db');
```

Note: My PHP version is 7.1

Note: My database name is not duplicate and sqlite3 must make it

Thanks for attention

Comment: the code you have will attempt to open a database. not create it

Comment: @Rahel SQLite will attempt to create the file if it doesn't exist. A failure like this would seem to indicate that it can't create the file which points to a permission issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is correct and should create the database file if it doesn't exist.

Most probably it's a user right issue, check the permissions of the folder where you are trying to create the file in.

Answer (score 0):

Check the directory permissions. The folder containing the SQLite file must be writable by the appropriate user.